# missing cocoa pods build phases

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Due to a bug I had to completely remove and re-add CocoaPods from my Xcode project.

As such I also removed the 2 build phases "Copy Pods Resources" and "Check Pods Manifest.lock".

After I re-added CocoaPods these 2 build phases were still missing even though from what I read online `pod install` should have added them.

How do I get them back?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the podfile try to re-install the cocoapods using the following commands

sudo gem install cocoapods-->touch podfile-->open podfile-->save your pod-->pod install. After the above steps check your target-->build phase.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of iOS (which is below) doesn't work for me. Don't know how to fix it((

problem is a cocoapods' dependence has some static resources which are not adding to the final .app file after building. The adding is written in bash script of being generated by cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same issue and found solution for myself. Sorry for such a late answer, but hope it might help somebody else.

There is an implemented Ruby gem by guy from Cocoapods team for deintegrating Cocoapods from the project. You can find it by this [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate). If you deintegrate Cocoapods from your project using this gem and run `pod install` afterwards, you'll see all Cocoapods build phases added back to your project.